# Java - How to create an object of each line being read in under a txt file

Tags: java, oop, file-io

I have the below method which reads each line of a txt file using hasNext, thus works but could anyone tell me how I would create an object of each line being read.

Thanks

```
private static Queue readFile(Scanner input) {
            Queue newQueue = new Queue ();
            while(input.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    String txtLine = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(txtLine);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR");  
                }       

            }
               return newQueue;
       }
```

Comment: What kind of object ? you could do MyObj obj = new MyObj(); obj.SetText(txtLine); and then adding it to an array maybe?

Comment: To answer this question, you would need to know what data is in the file, then define a POJO that would hold the data and initialize the object using the parsed data. Not too difficult, but impossible to answer without some real details

Answer (score 0):

You already did. String txtLine = input.nextLine(); creates a String object named txtLine. if you're trying to add it to the Queue, you need to do that too. Right now your code just prints them all out but never puts them in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
ArrayList<Queue> array = new ArrayList<Queue>();
        Queue newQueue = new Queue ();
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            try {
                String txtLine = input.nextLine();
                newQueue.setLine(txtLine);
                array.add(newQueue);
                System.out.println(txtLine);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");  
            }     
        }
           return array;
```